# Using Gronwall's Inequality with Random Variables

Tags: random-variables, integral-inequality

Currently, I've been working with an SDE and trying to get a bound on moments.  I have it down to something of the following form:

$$X(t)^p \leq a(t) + \int_0^t X(s)^pY(s) ds + \int_0^t X(s)^p dW_s$$

So taking expectations gives:

$$E[X(t)^p] \leq a(t) + E\left[\int_0^t X(s)^pY(s) ds\right] = E[X(t)^p] \leq a(t) + \int_0^t E\left[X(s)^pY(s)\right] ds$$

If $X$ and $Y$ were independent, I could use Fubini's Theorem and get a bound easily using Gronwall's Inequality. However, because $X$ is described from an SDE, $X$ and $Y$ are dependent. The problem with Holder's Inequality is that it will raise the power of $X(s)^p$ inside the integral and then Gronwall's Lemma can't be used. Does anyone know a way around this? I know $X$ is a positive r.v. and $Y$ has a normal distribution, but I don't those facts help much

Answer (score 0):

You can try
\begin{align*}
E[X(t)^p] &\leq a(t) + \int_0^t E\left[X(s)^pY(s)\right] \,ds\\
&= \int_0^t E\left[X(s)^pY(s)(1_{|Y| \leq M} +1_{|Y| \geq M})\right] \,ds\\
&\leq \int_0^t ME\left[X(s)^pY(s)1_{|Y| \leq M}\right] +E\left[X(s)^pY(s)1_{|Y| \geq M}\right] \,ds\\
&\leq \int_0^t ME\left[X(s)^p\right] + e(M) \,ds\\
&\leq \int_0^t ME\left[X(s)^p\right]  \,ds + t + e(M)\\
\end{align*}

Now use gronwall
$$E[X(t)^p] \leq (a(t) + e(M)t)e^{Mt} = \phi(M) $$

you can improve your inequality by considering the infimum in $M$ of $\phi(M)$

Comment: That's an interesting way to go about it and not one I would've thought of. Is $e(M)$ a specific function or are you using it to describe that there just exists some function of M?

Comment: $e(M)$ is just an error term for your second integral. Since Y is normal, that should decay very fast, depending on the growth of $X^p$ since you do not know the growth of $X^p$ use the first estimates to improve your next estimate. It's like a bootstrap.

Comment: A couple questions for you for my understanding: Why does $e(M)$ not depend on time? Also, since $Y$ is normal, then is this true for any $M \in \mathbb{R}$ or only on the nonnegative reals? It seems like I could just take $M=0$ and that shows that the expectation can't grow faster than linear in $t$ if $a(t)$ is linear in $t$

Comment: You are right, $e(M) = e(M,s)$ it depends on time. The larger you take $M$ the smaller is your quantity $e(M,s)$. Depending on the estimates you got, you can bound $\sup_{s\leq T} e(M,s) $ and consider now your function $e(M):= \sup_{s\leq T} e(M,s)$. So no, you can't take $M=0$. I edited the answer so you can see now we are using absolute values. It was a typo...

Comment: Ah ok yes I understand what you're saying. I was hoping to be able to say something about $\limsup_t E[X(t)^p]$ or a little bit stronger (in fact, I think there actually should be a universal constant $K$ so that $sup_{t \geq 0} E[X(t)^p] \leq K$). One thing I'm not sure how to do is to actually estimate $e(M)$. I understand the principle of treating it like an  error but I can't say I understand how to say something analytical about it

Comment: what is your SDE?

Comment: It is: 

$$dx_i = x_i(b_i - \sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij}x_j) dt + \sigma_ix_id\eta(t)$$
$$d\eta(t) = -\lambda\eta(t) dt + \alpha dW(t)$$

Here, $b_i, a_{ij} > 0$ for all $i,j$